# Chaining jobs in GNU parallel

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing, gnu

I am trying to execute this command with a tool called `TOOL.sh`. My parallel input values are 0.01, 0.02 and 0.05.

This command alone is supposed to produce four output files for each `--maf` input. I only want to keep the fourth file which is the log file and remove three other files (`.bim`, `.bed`, `.fam`) immediately after producing them as shown below. How do I write this code below so it would work?

```
PLINKfile=file
DIRplink=$PWD
OUTFILE="PWD/test"
parallel -j3 TOOL.sh --bfile ${PLINKfile} --maf {} --out $DIRplink/${OUTFILE}_{} | 
rm "${DIRplink}/${OUTFLE}_{}.bed" && 
rm "${DIRplink}/${OUTFLE}_{}.bim" &&
rm "${DIRplink}/${OUTFLE}_{}.fam"
::: 0.01 0.02 0.05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the outer shell parses `|` and `&&`, but you intended them to be part of the command that `parallel` executes. To do that, just enclose it in double quotes:

```
parallel -j3 "TOOL.sh --bfile ${PLINKfile} --maf {} --out $DIRplink/${OUTFILE}_{};
              rm ${DIRplink}/${OUTFILE}_{}.{bed,bim,fam}"
```

Alternatively, just delete all the unwanted files in one go after `parallel` finishes:

```
parallel -j3 TOOL.sh --bfile ${PLINKfile} --maf {} --out $DIRplink/${OUTFILE}_{}
rm ${DIRplink}/${OUTFILE}_*.{bed,bim,fam}
```